# How can I test the Java automatic instrumentation in OpenTelemetry?

Tags: java, testing, open-telemetry

I have a Java application with the GRPC API. And there is in the same repo a Java client library for this application.
I am using Maven as a build system.

How can I test that spans are correctly created and the app will work as I expect (i.e. instrumentation doesn't affect the application's logic)?

I tried to play with [the agent for testing](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/testing/agent-for-testing), but it seems that it should be configured heavily before being used as I can see in the different tests of Gradle plugins.

I have an idea that I should test this only on the integration level (i.e. set up the whole infrastructure for the tracing) but it would be cool to see the mistakes as early as possible :)

Also, I have plans to add the manual instrumentation to this app, because there is a custom Netty-based transport layer to another application and there is custom scheduling logic based on queues.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already solve your doubts related to your question, but first, the automated instrumentation logic should not affect your app logic, see this link --> (What’s the difference between automated instrumentation and manual instrumentation? section) https://isitobservable.io/open-telemetry/traces/how-to-instrument-your-code-using-opentelemetry.
Secondly, if you already use the automatic instrumentation in OpenTelemetry,  when the java agent is executed with your application, then you can check the span traces info and later assert the info that is interested for you.
Also, you can check the integration tests that they made related to the original repo:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/integration-tests.

I hope that info could help you.